# Let $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, define $Y=e^X$. Find CDF for $Y$ and then PDF (using the CDF)

Tags: probability-distributions

(a) Find CDF for $Y$.

(b) Then use the CDF to show that $Y$ has the following PDF

$$f(y)=\frac{1}{y \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} \exp \left(-\frac{(\log y-\mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}\right), \quad y>0$$

My problem is that I'm not allowing to use change of variables! I have to do this without.

I'm not sure how to start. A gentle push forward will be much appreciated.

Comment: Take $y > 0$. Then 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq \log y)
\end{equation}
because $\log$ is increasing on its domain. For part (b) think about the relationship between cdf's and pdf's.

Comment: When I differentiate CDF i get PDF. The hard part is actually finding the CDF.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$P(Y\leq a)=P(e^X\leq a)=P(X\leq \log(a))=\Psi(\log(a))$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\log(a)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dt$$
Now derive by $a$. [Leibniz_integral_rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$f_x(a)=\frac{d}{da} F_X(a)=\frac{d}{da} \int_{-\infty}^{\log(a)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(t-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} dt$$

$$= (\frac{d}{da}\log(a)) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(\log(a)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

$$= \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{\frac{-(\log(a)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

Answer (score 0):

To get CDF for $y\ge 0$: $P(Y\le y)=P(e^X\le y)=P(X\le lny)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int_{-\infty}^{lny}e^{-\frac{(w-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dw$.

To get the PDF simply take the derivative to get:  PDF $=\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(lny-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

Comment: I can't figure out what happens efter the last equality sign. Sorry.

Comment: I need to think a bit over this. i hope it is ok

Comment: In general let $g(x)=\int_a^{f(x)} h(w)dw$, then $g'(x)=f'(x)h(f(x))$.  You could look at it as $g(f(x))$, so $\frac {dg(f(x))}{dx}=\frac {dg(f(x))}{df}\frac{df(x)}{dx}$